# Users are granted Limited Access to private library

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

One of our SharePoint Online Site Collections is having a permission issue that is a little bothersome. Some of the site's Members are able to see a completely private document library. I am the only one with permissions on the library but Members of the site can still see it. They cannot see the contents of the library, but they are able to load it and see it in their navigation.

If I do a 'Check permissions', the members are showing as having limited access while the owners are not. These members have not been granted access to any file or folder within the private library.

This sounds like a bug, why are users able to see a Private document library without the contents? The shouldn't see it at all and if they try to access it they should get the 'Sorry, you don't have access to this page' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent users with limited access permission level access to Application Pages, you can go to site settings-> site collection feature, activate the feature “Limited-access user permission lockdown mode”.
[image]